# How do I fix my 'drawPlayer' (it has no errors)

Tags: javascript

I don't know what I did wrong about this code.

I've tried redoing the entire script many times, and even renamed it to see if it would change anything but it didn't.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head> 
<title>Purely's Tower Defense</title>
<style> 
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
    canvas {background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto}
 </style>
</head>
<body> 
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width='800' height='500'></canvas>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'); 
    var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var playerX = (canvas.width - playerWidth)/2;
    var playerY = canvas.height - playerHeight;
    var playerWidth = 30;
    var playerHeight = 30; 





function drawPlayer()
{
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, paddleHeight); 
ctx.closePath()
}


function draw()
{
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
drawPlayer(); 
}


draw();



</script>

</body>

</html>
```

I expected to just have the crystal & the player to spawn.

Comment: Could you put the error traceback? Otherwise no one can really help easily.
At first glance, you're calling `playerWidth` and `playerHeight` before declaring them.

Comment: what do you mean by declaring them?

Comment: When you type `var playerWidth` you essentially tell the code '_assign memory for this variable with this name_'. If you look through your code, you can see that you used it before **it** being declared (or in memory)

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate issues in your code:

1. You are defining `playerX` and `playerY` based on the `playerWidth` and `playerHeight` before they are defined
2. You are using `paddleHeight` instead of `playerHeight` in your `drawPlayer` function.

To fix this, you need to change your variable declaration order to have `playerWidth` and `playerHeight` before X and Y:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'); 
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
var playerWidth = 30;
var playerHeight = 30;
var playerX = (canvas.width - playerWidth)/2;
var playerY = canvas.height - playerHeight;
```

And change your drawPlayer function to use `playerHeight`

```
function drawPlayer()
{
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.fillRect(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight); 
  ctx.closePath();
}
```